# How do i make a 3x3 Grid Python

Tags: python

How would I be able to turn the code into a 3x3 grid?
Extra notes: In the Word.txt file there is ten 5 letter words.

Code:

```
f = open('Words.txt','r')

for word in f.read().split():
    print (word)
```

Code shows in a list

```
NIGHT
SMOKE
GHOST
TOOTH
ABOUT
CAMEL
BROWN
FUNNY
CHAIR
PRICE
```

Comment: Ten 5 letter words is 50 letters. How would you arrange that into a 3x3 grid without code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines, especially [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Give us sample input and output (both desired and what you get with your coding attempt).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
f = open('Words.txt','r')

words = f.read().split()

for i in range(3):
    print "\t".join(words[(i*3):(i*3+3)])
```

in my case:

```
words = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'] 

for i in range(3):
    print "\t".join(words[(i*3):(i*3+3)])
```

gave me:

```
1       2       3
4       5       6
7       8       9
```